# Setup Ethereum private blocjchain on server?

Tags: go-ethereum

I have an issue of connecting Ethereum private node on that particular Ip server in which I set up the ethereum node. I create a GUI of server enbale json rpc client on 127.0.0.1:8545. When I connect this address with web3 on my server gui I open a browser and hit my address "3.10.9.248/index.php" It shows connected with this "127.0.0.1:8545" and I am getting my ethereum node address and balance. When I hit this address outside the GUI of server 3.10.9.248/index.php then it shows nothing.

Its shows private node is running only in node GUI browser, not in any other browser. I want to create an API for ethereum node and provide access to another website to use that API.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the settings of your node.

Most likely your rpcaddr is 127.0.0.1. This means only the server/local machine can access this node/blockchain.

So you need to make a change in order to allow external connections.

The easy way to do this is with rpcaddr 0.0.0.0. But this is very insecure. Now everyone can access your node. So you should specify which IP can access your node.

Either manually input your device IP which wants access or build an API around it which handles this stuff for you.

Comment: Thanks for your response.I tried  to run geth with specific IP with this command "geth --allow-insecure-unlock --datadir ethchain --networkid 1 --rpcport 8545  --port 30303 --rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal,admin,txpool,debug" --rpc --maxpeers 0 --nodiscover  --rpccorsdomain "3.10.9.248" --rpcaddr "3.10.9.248" console" then It returns error "Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: listen tcp 3.10.9.248:8545: bind: cannot assign requested address"
When I added 127.0.0.1 this IP  then it is working fine.

Comment: cannot assign requested address means 3.10.9.248:8545 is used by another process. Please check lsof -i TCP| fgrep LISTEN

Comment: @MdRayhanulMasudSaom  I checked. It is not used by any other process

Comment: I think the address you are assigning is wrong. My ip is *.*.*.202 but I tried *.*.*.201. That time i got the same error. As your port is not used, the address might be wrong. Please check your assigned address.

Comment: Maybe firewall or something blocks your blockchain from opening a connection to 3.10.9.248. Or as other guy mentioned you already have something running on this port.

Comment: Connection is enable with 3.10.9.248 .Now I have one more question when genertae new account using personal.newAccount then how to retrieve their private key and public key as well.Is there any method for this?

Comment: you should probably mark this question as complete and open a new one as this is a seperate problem. I will answer it for you then